# Anonymous transactions with bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, privacy, tor

Is there any chance that people will identify me when I have nordvpn running in the background when making transactions with bitcoin core? Already done this

What are you recommendations to stay anonymous with bitcoin core and where to get information to achieve this?

Do I need to setup bitcoin core with tor?(seems advanced)
Read somewhere that bitcoin core automatically uses tor if it is installed. But hard to confirm.

Comment: A short answer should be a comment try https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70069/75001

Answer (score 1):

Your VPN provider at least is in a position to deanonymize you. Therefore, I would rather use TOR. It's not infallible, but many people have used it successfully to achieve relative anonymity. [Here's a short guide to setting up bitcoin core with TOR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md)

As Saxtheowl has already mentioned, however, both a VPN and TOR can only hide your IP address. There are many other ways to get deanonymized. Fortunately, there is a [comprehensive guide about everything you need to know about using Bitcoin in private](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy)

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN will anonymize you with the peers you are interacting with on the bitcoin network, but the transaction you are making on the blockchain will be recorded for ever.

To increase your privacy the best advice would be to use different address each time you receive bitcoin and to be careful if you plan to use exchange for fiat money because their address has been flagged as "exchange" for a long time.

In clear bitcoin does not guarantee privacy, you can read more here [Bitcoin Privacy](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/bitcoin-privacy)
and if you want more anonymity while using bitcoin you should read about the lightning network https://cointelegraph.com/lightning-network-101/what-is-lightning-network-and-how-it-works

Tor will not especially help you with privacy while using bitcoin and I dont think it will run automatically with bitcoin core if it installed